# Searching a set of keywords in a large string

Tags: java, solr, lucene, elasticsearch, nutch

I have to do a search in a text file or a large string to check if the text contains a set of keywords (could be millions). If it contains the keywords I have to highlight whatever keywords got matched. What approach should be taken for this? Does lucene provide a solution for this?

Comment: A text file _or_ a string? This does not quite look to be the same thing

Comment: Anyway -- you can use a trie or a bloom filter.

Comment: I meant, it could be a text file I need to search in or it could also be the text content as a string.

Comment: Hmm, a project I am working on would give a solution... You'd need to use a trie and you could record the position.

Comment: @fge I'll surely look into it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've tagged your question with Elasticsearch - if you're open to using ES I think Percolation with highlighting may fit what you need. You could register each keyword as a separate query with the percolator and then run each document or string thru it. It will return a list of the queries that matched. You can also combine it with highlighting.

http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-percolate.html

http://blog.qbox.io/elasticsesarch-percolator

Comment: I have a single document and millons of keywords.

Comment: so create 10000 separate percolation queries with 100 keywords in each plus highlighting. 10k percolation queries is not excessive, just requires scaling out to more ES nodes (it scales horizontally, mostly requires additional cpu).

Comment: Great! Just what I was looking for.

Answer (score -1):

You can use lucene [ShingleFilter](https://lucene.apache.org/core/3_6_0/api/all/org/apache/lucene/analysis/shingle/ShingleFilter.html)

You will find lots of example on the net, here is one http://www.massapi.com/class/sh/ShingleFilter.html

Comment: I will look into the solution provided. Thanks.

Comment: I do not have to create concatenated tokens. I have to search individual tokens and highlight it. For example - I want to look for "stack, overflow, exchange" (in real scenario it will be a large list)  in the text `"This stack is empty. Lets exchange places"`, then it should highlight(or atleast find) `stack` and `exchange` in the string.

Comment: Shingle gives you tokens.... you can write custom logic on how you want to use the tokens.

Comment: @Hirak - No, lucene `ShingleFilter` combines tokens in it's input TokenStream into ngrams (of a sort).  It is just not relevant here.